# Run scripts in the backend scope / set a global $BE_USER object?

Tags: extbase, typo3-8.x

I want to create and fill pages with content programmatically with my extbase extension.
I'm going through [this](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/8.7/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/UsingDataHandler/Index.html) tutorial and seeing the big warning panel:
[image]
Thanks for the warning...but how do I do this??? I can't find the answer :(

Answer (score 1):

According to [changeset 79240](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/79240) a special admin user is created automatically and when you're using CLI scripts (ie. Extbase command controllers), this user will be used.
So in short, it seems that the documentation needs to be updated and that you don't have to take special care about the BE_USER object, unless you want to have a another user registered as creator of the content.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure it out and my current guess is that this warning has something to do with the difference between frontend plugins and backend modules. Since I was using a frontend plugin this didn't work. So I'm trying to create a backend module now in order to solve this, which I never did before so this will take me a while to figure it out.

Comment: Exactly - the guide you found is in terms of CLI scripts as the DataHandler is only used in _backend_ and _cli_ context.